# How do I make my Mac speakers sound like iPad 2 speakers?

Tags: audio

I am the developer of an app that uses voice recordings. I need to have an idea of what the recordings will sound like on an iPad. I have an iPad, but I'd like to change some settings on my Mac speakers so that every sound sounds like it's coming out of an iPad speaker.

Comment: It really depends on your Mac. Why not use headphones to get things a bit closer? Also, you'll need to model the iPad in terms of how it's held and positioned. Cases and reflected sound is much lower than if you hold it dock first horizontal and right in front of your face. Same goes for the Mac - controlling the speaker position and materials it reflects off will make huge difference in sound quality.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your budget, I would use something like Rogue Amoeba's [Audio Hijack 3](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) to process the sound output and model the speakers of the iPad.

If you have extra budget, you'll want to record in a acoustically quiet room some songs and test tone generators out of the actual iPad speakers (and maybe sample several devices to see how much variation is present in the iPad line). Use a high quality microphone if possible for this.

You'll have issues correcting for the Mac speakers though and should probably invest in some good powered studios monitors or headphones if you really want to hear what the iPad would sound like.

If you don't have decent audio analysis software, you might want to look at something like [Spectre](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spectre-realtime-audio-meters/id436872608?mt=12)

p.s. FWIW - My MacBook 2015 (40% volume) sounds about the same as my iPad Air 2 (90% volume) and passing the MacBook audio through the AUBandpass filter. Configure the bandpass to be centered around 2 kHz and a width of 5000 cents.